# Got an eight pack, where do I go from there?

Tags: muscle

Just finished fasting and lost around 6 kilograms, now my abdominal muscles are perfectly visible.

Now I want to gain back even more weight, but only muscle weight cause I want to maintain my eight pack, how do I proceed on doing that diet wise?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking for here. A complete training program? Food plan?

Comment: Are your abs only there because you're skinny or because you have solid strong abs?

Comment: This is a duplicate of several questions on the site.